# Error om.appsnipp.niasbaratepresensi.welcome_activity cannot be cast to com.appsnipp.niasbaratepresensi.DashboardActivity

Tags: android, android-studio, aws-session-manager

I made an automatic login on Android, the code is below. But I get this error:

---

**E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.appsnipp.nbpresensi, PID: 14850
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.appsnipp.nbpresensi/com.appsnipp.niasbaratepresensi.welcome_activity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.appsnipp.niasbaratepresensi.welcome_activity cannot be cast to com.appsnipp.niasbaratepresensi.DashboardActivity
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3454)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3593)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:140)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2126)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7684)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:980)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.appsnipp.niasbaratepresensi.welcome_activity cannot be cast to com.appsnipp.niasbaratepresensi.DashboardActivity
at com.appsnipp.niasbaratepresensi.SessionManager.checkLogin(SessionManager.java:51)
at com.appsnipp.niasbaratepresensi.welcome_activity.onCreate(welcome_activity.java:19)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7817)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7806)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3424)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3593) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:140) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2126) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7684) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:980) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 14850 SIG: 9
Process 14850 terminated.**

---

This my welcome activity code:

```
 public class welcome_activity extends AppCompatActivity {
        SessionManager sessionManager;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
    
            sessionManager = new SessionManager(this);
            sessionManager.checkLogin();
    
            HashMap<String, String> user = sessionManager.getUserDetail();
            String mNip = user.get(sessionManager.NIP);
            if (mNip.equals(mNip)) {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(welcome_activity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }, 2000);
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(welcome_activity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is my session manager:

```
public class SessionManager {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    public Context context;
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    private static final String PREF_NAME = "LOGIN";
    private static final String LOGIN = "IS_LOGIN";
    public static final String NM_LENGKAP = "NM_LENGKAP";
    public static final String NIP = "NIP";
    public static final String PASSWORD = "PASSWORD";
    public static final String JABATAN = "JABATAN";
    public static final String OPD = "OPD";
    public static final String GAMBAR = "GAMBAR";

    public SessionManager(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    }

    public void createSession(String nm_lengkap, String nip, String password, String jabatan,String opd,String gambar) {
        editor.putBoolean(LOGIN, true);
        editor.putString(NM_LENGKAP, nm_lengkap);
        editor.putString(NIP, nip);
        editor.putString(PASSWORD, password);
        editor.putString(JABATAN, jabatan);
        editor.putString(OPD, opd);
        editor.putString(GAMBAR, gambar);
        editor.apply();

    }

    public boolean isLoggin() {
        return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(LOGIN, false);
    }

    public void checkLogin() {
        if (!this.isLoggin()) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(i);
            ((DashboardActivity) context).finish();
        }
        if (!this.isLoggin()) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(i);
            ((welcome_activity) context).finish();
        }
        if (!this.isLoggin()) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(i);
            ((Absen_Activity1) context).finish();
        }
        if (!this.isLoggin()) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(i);
            ((Absen_Activity2) context).finish();
        }
        if (!this.isLoggin()) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(i);
            ((UbahPwd) context).finish();
        }
        if (!this.isLoggin()) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(i);
            ((Lihat_Absen1) context).finish();
        }
        if (!this.isLoggin()) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(i);
            ((Lihat_Absen2) context).finish();
        }
        if (!this.isLoggin()) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(i);
            ((Sudah_Activity) context).finish();
        }
        if (!this.isLoggin()) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(i);
            ((ProfileActivity) context).finish();
        }
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetail() {
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<>();
        user.put(NM_LENGKAP, sharedPreferences.getString(NM_LENGKAP, null));
        user.put(NIP, sharedPreferences.getString(NIP, null));
        user.put(PASSWORD, sharedPreferences.getString(PASSWORD, null));
        user.put(JABATAN, sharedPreferences.getString(JABATAN, null));
        user.put(OPD, sharedPreferences.getString(OPD, null));
        user.put(GAMBAR, sharedPreferences.getString(GAMBAR , null));
        return user;
    }

    public void logout() {
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
        Intent i = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Could someone tell me what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing `SessionManager` with `welcome_activity` context, but casting it to `DashboardActivity` context. That's why it is failing.

Don't finish a context from within SessionManager (return a value, use it to finish inside calling activity)

Your `checkLogin` function is boilerplate and has unsafe casting. You can try this:

In SessionManager:

```
public boolean checkLogin(){
     return !this.isLoggin();
}
```

In activity:

```
        sessionManager = new SessionManager(this);
        if(!sessionManager.checkLogin()){
            Intent i = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(i);
            finish();
            return;
         }
```

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't work, is there another solution?

Comment: can you post stacktrace after the additions?

Comment: have you told me the link that discusses auto login with session manager?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to. You said the code I gave doesn't work, so I wanted to know if you give me the stacktrace after you used my code, or if the stacktrace didn't change.

Comment: it worked, but when i went back to login i pressed again the activity was brought back into the dashboard again,